# how to remove multiple query string variable from url using htaccess or other technique

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, query-string

My website has dynamic pages such as

```
http://www.example.com/detailpage.php?sn=1%20&&%20database=news
http://www.example.com/detailpage.php?sn=1%20&&%20database=article
http://www.example.com/detailpage.php?sn=1%20&&%20database=interview
```

and many other

I want to remove or hide query string variable from url and display as

```
http://www.krishisansar.com/detailpage/news/1
http://www.krishisansar.com/detailpage/article/1
```

Is it possible to change querystring as slash ? if not, how to remove & and make as

```
/news=1 or /news=2, 
/article=1 or /article=2 .
```

By this, I can validate from w3c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detailpage\.php\?sn=([^\s&]+)&database=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ detailpage/%2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^detailpage/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ detailpage.php?sn=$2&database=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, still url appears as same. Perhaps, I can't explain my problem in meaningful way. My sub-directory (news) index file contains this code : **<a href='../detailpage.php?sn=$sn&amp;database=news'>..</a> same like sub-directory(article) index file contains this code : <a href='../detailpage.php?sn=$sn&amp;database=article'>..</a> . all sub directory has same way.  In detailpage.php it is passed as sn=$sn&amp;database=$database** and displayed as detailpage.php?sn=$sn&database='' (according name). I want to display $database/$sn. Thanks for your concern

Comment: ok check updated rule. Make sure this is in root .htaccess (a level above news)

Comment: Fantastic. you really saved my time. this worked perfectly for me. According your code, url is displayed as my wish, but print mysql error. I suppose last line RewriteRule ^detailpage/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ detailpage.php?sn=$2database=$1 [L,QSA,NC] **is missing &** between **sn=$2** and **database=$1**. When I add **&** error is solved but css rule is disturbed. I am confused, adding **&**  is wrong or my internal structure is wrong ?

Comment: Ah that's right, I had `&` missing in last rule. I have fixed it now. For css/js issue add  this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: Nice answer. The original links were a mess.

Comment: Yeah ! **<base href="/" />** works. @anubhava Thanks for your valuable time and continuous support